# “Enter Password” for Touch ID authentication Refers?

Tags: ios, touch-id

Am implementing Touch ID authentication in my app as well as a separate login screen. In Touch ID authentication, Which Password is “Enter Password" referring. Currently I'm setting my own login screen if Touch ID password button clicked. Is it a correct way or whether "Enter password" has some reference with device passcode. If so how do I check with that??

Answer (score 2):

Enter Password option in touch ID is not referring the device pin actually. It is the password for your app.

Comment: Thanks :) If so, I should save password on initial launch and then verify from next launch?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you must do. Save it securely in the keychain.